# Magento connects to wrong mongodb server

Tags: magento-enterprise, configuration, server-setup, mongo

I have copied my project from production environment into dev environment and so needed to update configs to the ones used for dev environment.

I updated the  in app/etc/mongogento.xml and other config files but my Mage code still selects the **production** mongodb server ("**dbserver**:27017") instead of the **dev** mongodb server ("**localhost**:27017"). I have done a global search but I don't see "dbserver" mentioned anywhere. Tried restarting nginx abd php-fpm too to see if a value from cache is being used but i still get the same error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection timeout calling ismaster on 'dbserver:27017'] in /var/www/api/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/functions.php:431 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/api/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/functions.php(431): MongoDB\Driver\Manager->selectServer() #1 /var/www/api/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Collection.php(651): MongoDB\select_server() #2 /var/www/api/app/code/community/Smile/MongoCore/Model/Resource/Override/Core/Store/Collection.php(92): MongoDB\Collection->find() #3 /var/www/api/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(752): Smile_MongoCore_Model_Resource_Override_Core_Store_Collection->load() #4 /var/www/api/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(636): Varien_Data_Collection->count() #5 /var/www/api/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(477): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores() #6 /var/www/api/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(285): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore() #7 /var/www/api/app/Mage.php(627): Mag in /var/www/api/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/functions.php on line 431
```

Note that mongo db connection using MongoDB Client works properly since I am explicitly mentioning the server name like so:

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

My test code producing the error:

```
$root = (filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DOCUMENT_ROOT'));
require $root. '/vendor/autoload.php'; // include Composer's autoloader
require_once $root . '/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('admin');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, Magento was reading the server configuration from redis database instead of from it's config file. Deleting all data from the database solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

To change your Magento 2 database server hostname, database username, password or database name, you need to edit below file.

//app/etc/env.php
Navigate to your Magento 2 installation directory and edit app/etc/env.php configuration file in your favorite editor and search for following settings and do necessary changes.

'db' =>
  array (
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'connection' =>
    array (
      'default' =>
      array (
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => 'database_name',
        'username' => 'database_username',
        'password' => 'database_password',
        'active' => '1',
      ),
    ),
  ),

Comment: Im using Magento 1 (EE 1.14). The only files under /app/etc/ are - config.xml,enterprise.xml,local.xml,mongogento.xml and a modules directory. I've already updated  mongogento.xml with the correct connection_string